# postgres select for update query meaning

Tags: php, postgresql

What does this following query means in postgres. I know it is something about locking but someone can please exlpain.

```
select col1, col2 from table where col1=123 for update;
```

Actually i have a table like

```
id  col1  col2  receipt_id  receipt_year
1   ddd   ggg   1           2018
2   ddd   eee   2           2018
```

I need to reset receipt_id every year to 1. i.e 1/2017, 1/2018 so on.
i am using query

```
select max(receipt_id) from table where receipt_year=$current_year;
```

and then if id is found, i add 1 to it else i set it to 1.

is it correct way ?

```
id  col1  col2  receipt_id  receipt_year
1   ddd   ggg   1           2018
2   ddd   eee   2           2018
```

For year 2019:

```
id  col1  col2  receipt_id  receipt_year
1   ddd   ggg   1           2018
2   ddd   eee   2           2018
3   lol   lpl   1           2019
```

And currently i am doing it this way:

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$sql = SELECT MAX(receipt_id) AS receipt_id FROM table WHERE receipt_year=:year;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':year' => $current_year));
$receipt_ido = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ( ! empty($receipt_ido)) {
   $receipt_id = ($receipt_ido + 1);
} else {
   $receipt_id = 1;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us a few more rows of sample data.  Then, show us what the output should be.  Your language is not clear (at least not to me).

Comment: Show us the table before *and* after resetting the `receipt_id`.

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question.  No one is going to see this thread except for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) makes it pretty clear what the `FOR UPDATE` clause does:

> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT FOR UPDATE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends.

Also, `FOR UPDATE` will wait for another transaction which has an update lock on the record to finish before beginning.

In plainer language, `FOR UPDATE` tagged to the end of a `SELECT` ensures that the select will complete without any updates taking place at the same time as the select.  This means your select would return an accurate snapshot of the data, without the possibility of getting intermediate data from the record.